# python: parse a List within a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
response = {'links': [{'rel': 'self', 'href': 'XXXXXXX'}], 'id': 22, 'attribute_type': 'Number', 'label': 'Type', 'required': True, 'constrained': True, 'order': 2, 'allowed_values': [{'links': [], 'value': 701, 'label': 'Manual', 'order': 1, 'is_default': True, 'is_active': True}, {'links': [], 'value': 702, 'label': 'Automation', 'order': 2, 'is_default': False, 'is_active': True}, {'links': [], 'value': 703, 'label': 'Performance', 'order': 3, 'is_default': False, 'is_active': True}, {'links': [], 'value': 704, 'label': 'Scenario', 'order': 4, 'is_default': False, 'is_active': True}], 'multiple': False, 'data_type': 3, 'searchable': True, 'free_text_search': False, 'search_key': 'type', 'system_field': True, 'original_name': 'Type', 'is_active': True}
```

so I am able to get the id in the response as such:

```
for r in response:
    if r['label'] == 'Type'
        return r['id']
```

However, I am trying to get 'value' in the 'allowed_values' list in the response.

```
'allowed_values': [{'links': [], 'value': 701, 'label': 'Manual', 'order': 1, 'is_default': True, 'is_active': True}, {'links': [], 'value': 702, 'label': 'Automation', 'order': 2, 'is_default': False, 'is_active': True}, {'links': [], 'value': 703, 'label': 'Performance', 'order': 3, 'is_default': False, 'is_active': True}, {'links': [], 'value': 704, 'label': 'Scenario', 'order': 4, 'is_default': False, 'is_active': True}]
```

Is this possible, if so how?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

With Anton's help, this is what I ended up using!

```
if r.get('allowed_values'):
   av = r.get('allowed_values')
      for av_values in av:
          if av_values['label'] == subvalue:
             field_value = av_values['value']
             return field_value
```

Comment: @AntonvBR yes, would this print out 702, 703, 704 and so on?

Comment: Yes, well to print them out you could loop the list comprehension: `for i in values: print i`. The key here is list comprehensions. They are very powerful! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is where list comprehensions comes in handy in Python. Hmm, pretty basic though. I will see if I can find a dupe.

```
values = [i['value'] for i in response['allowed_values']]
print(values)  # --> prints[701, 702, 703, 704]
```